# Custom builtin in Jena

Tags: java, eclipse, jena, built-in, jena-rules

This is the code I have written but the new built-in does not seem to work. I get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.impl.LPRuleSyntaxException: Syntax error in backward rule: matematica Unknown builtin operation mysum

Can anyone tell me where the error is? Here is my code:

```
package JenaRules;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyCreationException;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.OWLOntologyStorageException;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.Query;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.InfModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.Reasoner;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.*;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.builtins.BaseBuiltin;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.FileManager;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.RDFS;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.ReasonerVocabulary;

public class RulesOntology_MT {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws OWLOntologyStorageException,
    OWLOntologyCreationException, IOException  {

        BuiltinRegistry.theRegistry.register(new BaseBuiltin() {
             @Override
             public String getName() {
                    return "mysum";
                }
             @Override
                public int getArgLength() {
                    return 2;
                }
             @Override
                public boolean bodyCall(Node[] args, int length, RuleContext context) {
                    checkArgs(length, context);
                    BindingEnvironment env = context.getEnv();
                    Node n1 = getArg(0, args, context);
                    Node n2 = getArg(1, args, context);
                    if (n1.isLiteral() && n2.isLiteral()) {
                        Object v1 = n1.getLiteralValue();
                        Object v2 = n2.getLiteralValue();
                        Node sum = null;
                        if (v1 instanceof Number && v2 instanceof Number) {
                            Number nv1 = (Number)v1;
                            Number nv2 = (Number)v2;
                            int sumInt = nv1.intValue()+nv2.intValue();
                            sum = Util.makeIntNode(sumInt);
                            return env.bind(args[2], sum);
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }

        });

        // NON SERVE

        //      final String exampleRuleString2 =
        //              "[mat1: equal(?s ?p )\n\t-> print(?s ?p ?o),\n\t   (?s ?p ?o)\n]"+
        //                      "";

        final String exampleRuleString =    
                "[matematica:"+
                        "(?p http://www.semanticweb.org/prova_rules_M#totale_crediti ?x)"+
                        " -> " +
                        "(?p rdf:type  http://www.semanticweb.org/prova_rules_M#:Persona)"+
                        "(?e rdf:type  http://www.semanticweb.org/prova_rules_M#:Esame)"+
                        "(?p  http://www.semanticweb.org/prova_rules_M#:haSostenutoEsameDi ?e)"+
                        "(?e http://www.semanticweb.org/prova_rules_M/persona#crediti_esame ?cr)"+
                        "mysum(?cr,2)"+
                        "]";

        System.out.println(exampleRuleString);

        /* I tend to use a fairly verbose syntax for parsing out my rules when I construct them
         * from a string. You can read them from whatever other sources.
         */
        final List<Rule> rules;
        try( final BufferedReader src = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(exampleRuleString.getBytes()))) ) {
            rules = Rule.parseRules(Rule.rulesParserFromReader(src));
        }


        /* Construct a reasoner and associate the rules with it  */
        // create an empty non-inferencing model

        GenericRuleReasoner reasoner = (GenericRuleReasoner) GenericRuleReasonerFactory.theInstance().create(null);
        reasoner.setRules(rules);


        /* Create & Prepare the InfModel. If you don't call prepare, then
         * rule firings and inference may be deferred until you query the
         * model rather than happening at insertion. This can make you think
         * that your Builtin is not working, when it is.
         */

        InfModel infModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, ModelFactory.createDefaultModel());
        infModel.prepare();
        infModel.createResource(RDFS.Class);

        //write down the result in RDFXML form
        infModel.write(System.out);

    }
}
```

Comment: "*but the new built-in does not seem to work. It is not recognized*" > I don't understand this description of your problem. What problem are you seeing? A compile error?  A runtime error? Unexpected output?

Comment: My error is :

Exception in thread "main" com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.impl.LPRuleSyntaxException: Syntax error in backward rule: matematica
Unknown builtin operation mysum.


I do not know how I can set the reasoner, allowing it to recognise the new built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the code that you provided, and Apache Jena `2.11.1`, I cannot replicate the exception you are getting. Do note that when you call `BuiltinRegistry.theRegistry.register(...)`, you *are* telling the reasoner that the builtin exists.

**Solution**

The exception that you *are* getting is likely because, in your *actual* code, you are not calling `BuiltinRegistry.theRegistry.register(...)` prior to calling `Rule.parseRules(Rule.rulesParserFromReader(src));`, so as far as the rule parser is concerned, you are using a `Builtin` which doesn't exist. To fix it, merely call `register` before parsing your rules. The toy example provided does not have this problem.

**Using the example provided**

I also noted that the provided code example did not include anything that would actually stimulate the rule to fire, so, in lieu of `infModel.createResource(RDFS.Class);`, I added the following lines:

```
final Resource s = infModel.createResource();
final Property p = infModel.createProperty("http://www.semanticweb.org/prova_rules_M#totale_crediti");
final Resource o = infModel.createResource();
infModel.add(s,p,o);
```

This stimulated the rule to fire, and led to the following exception trace:

```
com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.BuiltinException: Error in clause of rule (matematica) mysum: builtin mysum not usable in rule heads
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.builtins.BaseBuiltin.headAction(BaseBuiltin.java:86)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.impl.RETEConflictSet.execute(RETEConflictSet.java:184)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.impl.RETEConflictSet.add(RETEConflictSet.java:81)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.impl.RETEEngine.requestRuleFiring(RETEEngine.java:249)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.impl.RETETerminal.fire(RETETerminal.java:80)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.impl.RETEClauseFilter.fire(RETEClauseFilter.java:227)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.impl.RETEEngine.inject(RETEEngine.java:469)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.impl.RETEEngine.runAll(RETEEngine.java:451)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.impl.RETEEngine.add(RETEEngine.java:174)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.FBRuleInfGraph.performAdd(FBRuleInfGraph.java:654)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.impl.GraphBase.add(GraphBase.java:202)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.add(ModelCom.java:1138)
    at SO.test(SO.java:108)
```

As a note: my test class is `SO.java` and line 108 is where we call `infModel.add(s,p,o)`.

The exception that I get is different than the exception you encountered, but it is worth explaining. The implementation that you provided implements `Builtin#bodyCall(...)`, but not `Builtin#headAction(...)`. We can see the exception is thrown from [`BaseBuiltin#headAction(...)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.jena/jena-core/2.11.0/com/hp/hpl/jena/reasoner/rulesys/builtins/BaseBuiltin.java#BaseBuiltin.headAction%28com.hp.hpl.jena.graph.Node%5b%5d%2Cint%2Ccom.hp.hpl.jena.reasoner.rulesys.RuleContext%29). This default behavior assumes that you didn't implement the method because your `Builtin` doesn't support it. In the toy problem, this is correct behavior because the example implementation *cannot* be used in rule heads.

Comment: Interesting that "Syntax error in **backward rule**: matematica Unknown builtin operation mysum".  Isn't the rule as written in the question (with one thing in the body and five in the head) a forward rule?

Comment: You are absolutely right. The toy example provided doesn't seem to reflect the actual rule in question.

Comment: Hello everybody!

Many thanks for your contribution. I have solved the problem thanks to you.

I have built a customized built-in!

Comment: By the way, if the answer was helpful for this, and your other questions, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).